# matching 1d arrays in 2d arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compare a one dimensional array in a collection of 1 dimensional array using python. For example:

```
import numpy as np;
data= np.array( [  [1,2] , [2,3] ,[3,4], [1,2] , [0,9] ])
#I want to get the indexes of [1,2] which are 0 and 3 for above list
```

Does anyone have an idea how to implement that in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [116]: data = np.array( [  [1,2] , [1,3] ,[3,4], [1,2] , [0,9] ])

In [117]: np.where(np.prod(data == [1,2], axis = -1))
Out[117]: (array([0, 3]),)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can't we think of a more generic version?

Comment: What part of the problem can generalize? The dimension of `data`? The values 1 and 2? Are you always looking for rows, or might you sometimes be looking for columns?

Comment: Actually the length of the array being compared, can't we do that without the logical AND?

Comment: Well, there is `np.where(np.logical_and(*(data[:,i] == x for i, x in enumerate([1, 2]))))`. I suspect there is a better way, however.

Comment: That looks really interesting, Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Actually, my suggestion to use `np.logical_and` is a mistake: It can not take more than two arrays as arguments. Maybe use `np.prod` instead. I've edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: you could use `np.logical_and` you just need to use `np.logical_and.reduce(..., axis=-1)`, which is equivalent to `np.all`, of course the `np.prod` does the same job here...